# RHEL SELinux blocking Apache access to PostgreSQL

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, postgresql, django, selinux

I'm running a Django app that uses PostgreSQL. The server is running RHEL 6.5 with SELinux. I'm having an issue where the Django app can't connect to the DB, and I think it's because SELinux is blocking it. Here's the error I'm seeing in Django:

`could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

How can I fix this? I came across [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/314393/selinux-prevents-apache-from-writing-to-pgbouncers-unix-domain-socket), but I'm not sure how to apply the solution (`chcon -t postgresql_exec_t /path/to/pgbouncer`) to my problem.

Thanks!

[edit]
Here's what `/var/log/audit/audit.log` looks like when I try to access the site:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1396289984.549:9245): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=16975 comm="httpd" name=".s.PGSQL.5432" dev=sda1 ino=2359354 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0 tclass=sock_file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1396289984.549:9245): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=no exit=-13 a0=10 a1=7fe625273aa0 a2=6e a3=0 items=0 ppid=16943 pid=16975 auid=22383 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=1213 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1396289984.756:9246): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=16975 comm="httpd" name=".s.PGSQL.5432" dev=sda1 ino=2359354 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0 tclass=sock_file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1396289984.756:9246): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=no exit=-13 a0=10 a1=7fe624d87890 a2=6e a3=0 items=0 ppid=16943 pid=16975 auid=22383 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=1213 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1396289984.757:9247): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=16975 comm="httpd" name=".s.PGSQL.5432" dev=sda1 ino=2359354 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0 tclass=sock_file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1396289984.757:9247): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=no exit=-13 a0=10 a1=7fe625342c20 a2=6e a3=0 items=0 ppid=16943 pid=16975 auid=22383 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=1213 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1396289984.758:9248): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=16975 comm="httpd" name=".s.PGSQL.5432" dev=sda1 ino=2359354 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0 tclass=sock_file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1396289984.758:9248): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=no exit=-13 a0=10 a1=7fe625603ac0 a2=6e a3=0 items=0 ppid=16943 pid=16975 auid=22383 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=1213 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
```

[edit2]

Here are some relevant SELinux options that I've enabled.

`-bash-4.1$ sudo getsebool -a | grep httpd_can_network_connect_db
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> on
-bash-4.1$ sudo getsebool -a | grep allow_user_postgresql_connect
allow_user_postgresql_connect --> on`

Comment: What's in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`?

Comment: I just added the contents of `audit.log` to the post.

Comment: what about: setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1 and setsebool -P allow_user_postgresql_connect 1 ?

Comment: I already had the first option enabled. I just turned on the second option, and I'm still seeing the same error. I updated the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, with the help of a sysadmin here, the problem is now fixed. As it turns out, the SELinux context assigned to the binaries in `/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin` was wrong. All it took to fix this was `chcon -t postgresql_exec_t /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin`. To change the context on symbolic links, just add `-h`.

Comment: I tried that but I'm still getting the socket error. http://superuser.com/questions/777676/php-cant-connect-to-postgresql-with-permission-denied-error-with-selinux

Answer (score 10):

For future readers, for me, just setting the bool to allow httpd to make DB connections was sufficient; i.e.:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

You can check/verify that the setting is set by:

```
getsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db
```

which should return '... => on'

After that, if you tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log and re-attempt your operation, it should work.